# Не получается правильно сложить числа в строке kotlin

Tags: алгоритм, kotlin

Изучаю kotlin, столкнулся с проблемой.
На вход дается строка, состоящая из целых чисел без пробела. Необходимо найти сумму четных чисел и реализовать алгоритм отдельной функцией.
Прим., для строки 660308340, вывод будет 24 (6+6+8+4).
Всё бы ничего, да только в цикле у меня почему-то прибавляется всегда по 54, и на вывод идет для данной строки 360
Для проверки я добавил в цикл вывод значения обрабатываемой в данный момент цифры (i) и значение b. i отображается корректно, но вот b с каждым новым проходом увеличивается почему-то на 54

```
fun calculateEvenDigits(input:String): Int{
    var b = 0
    for(i in input){
        if (i.toInt() % 2 == 0){
            b+=i.toInt()
            println("i = $i, b = $b")
        }
    }
    return b
}
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a : String? = readLine()
    if(a!=null){
        print(calculateEvenDigits(a.toString()))
    }
}
```

Comment: Если на вход дать другую строку, то тоже 54?

Comment: Эникейщик, да, при вводе иных значений, почему-то всегда прибавляется по 54

Comment: Кое-что интересное заметил, в строке, где я вывожу i и b, попробовал написать вывод i с преобразованием в Int  println("i = ${i.toInt()}, b = $b"), но при этом, как раз появляются те злополучные 54. То есть как строка i выводится корректно, но при преобразовании в Int функцией toInt() происходит какая-то белиберда. Как с этим бороться?

Comment: 54 - ascii код для символа "6".  Что-то не так в конвертации.

Comment: Я уже нашел выход, но как-то похоже на костыль. В строчке сложения изменил на b+=(i.toString()).toInt(). Теперь все отображается корректно, но теперь другой вопрос, можно ли как-то избавиться от этого?

Comment: Вычитайте ASCII код нуля (`48`) и будет все хорошо. `input` имеет тип `String`, когда Вы итерируетесь по строке, то вы получаете `Char` (то есть Ваше `i` является символом), который при конвертации в число даёт ASCII код символа. Решается это вычитанием из полученного значения 48-ми)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, Как вариант, тоже об этом подумал, только тогда, как я понимаю, в случае введения букв, будут вводиться также цифры. Так что, наверное, лучше будет использовать преобразование `Char` в `String` и `String` в `Int`

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, а нет, всё нормально, у меня же в программе используется проверка делимости на два, так что буквы просто по условию не пройдут. Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @ВиталийСорокин: не совсем! Смотрите, буква `B` имеет ASCII код `66`, например. Так что условие делимости ее ещё как пустит. Так что если строка может содержать что-то кроме десятичных цифр - лучше все таки внедрить проверку)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, всё-таки да, Вы правы)  
Спасибо за консультацию!

Comment: @ВиталийСорокин: да не за что) Удачи в Ваших делах!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При преобразовании символа строки с помощью метода `toInt()` вы получаете код символа (например `'0'.toInt() == 48`), а не значение цифры. Можно от каждого символа отнимать код нуля, тогда получится числовое значение (считаем что на входе только цифры):

```
fun calculateEvenDigits(input: String): Int {
    var sum = 0
    for(c in input) {
        val digit = c - '0'
        if (digit % 2 == 0) {
            sum += digit
            println("c = $c, sum = $sum")
        }
    }
    return sum
}
```

Для строки `660308340` вывод будет такой:

```
c = 6, sum = 6
c = 6, sum = 12
c = 0, sum = 12
c = 0, sum = 12
c = 8, sum = 20
c = 4, sum = 24
c = 0, sum = 24
24
```

Также можно использовать метод `Character.getNumericValue`. Для символов от `'0'` до `'9'` он возвращает соответствующие числовые значения, для букв латинского алфавита от `'a'` до `'z'` и от `'A'` до `'Z'` возвращает значения от 10 до 35, для остальных символов возвращает -1. В примере кода выше просто меняете строку `val digit = c - '0'` на `val digit = Character.getNumericValue(c)`.

Answer (score 4):

Конвертируем Char в String и лишь затем в Int, иначе получим код символа.

```
fun calculateEvenDigits(input: String): Int {
    var sum: Int = 0
    var temp: Int = 0
    for (x in input) {
        temp = x.toString().toInt()
        if (temp % 2 == 0) sum += temp
    }
    return sum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Куда легче написать так .Смысл почти тот же ,что и выше,только немного через другие функции получается (пока что только учу Kotlin), может и не прав

```
fun calculateEvenDigits(input:String): Int{
    var cnt:Int = 0
    
    for (c in input) {
        val i:Int = Character.getNumericValue(c)
        if (i % 2 == 0) cnt += i
    }
    return cnt
}
```